# what is need of start of selection in normal report programming?

Tags: abap

We can write select queries in `END-OF-SELECTION` and initialization event also,  so what is the need of `START-OF-SELECTION`. Also why we shouldn't we write select in `INITIALIZATION` and `END-OF-SELECTION`?

Comment: Please don't use the SMS style, write plain words: SOS -> START-OF-SELECTION ; EOS -> END-OF-SELECTION. Also your question is too broad ; consider first reading the official language documentation, and ask questions with more details.

Answer (score 1):

**`INITIALIZATION`** event block triggers after `LOAD-OF-PROGRAM` event and Before *SELECTION SCREEN* processing blocks.
So, if you define standard selection screen, It'll be called again after execution which raise `INITIALIZATION` event. 
And if you write the `SELECT` statement in `INITIALIZATION` block it load data again after the execution which is no use.

**`END-OF-SELECTION`** mainly associated with logical database in executable program, if the logical database has fully completed its work, 
it triggers `END-OF-SELECTION` event, Otherwise it triggeres directly after `START-OF-SELECTION`. 
It tells the server that all the database reading is completed and no further reading is going to take place and release the lock on database.
That's why it doesn't considered as good practices, it mainly used for displaying output.

You can check the documentaion:
[Report Events](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenabap_processing_blocks.htm)

[Event Flow Process](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenreporting_process.htm)

[Logical Databases - Associated with Executable Programs](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenldb_usage_executable.htm)

Comment: I like [this graphical representation of events from the SAP Library](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/9f/db9bb935c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, INITIALIZATION is triggered when the program has been loaded, and before the screen is shown.
That event must be used to **prepare** the program to run.
START-OF-SELECTION is triggered when the program is asked to run (from the SELECTION SCREEN).

So, if your program has no selection screen or you are not using previous events, you can skip your START-OF-SELECTION, **but** if you are using a single "before" event (INIT, AT SELECTION...), you must tell the compiler (or whatever its name is) where the program really starts.

In any case, I believe it's a good practice to use it, because it adds "readiness" to your code: the guys who will need to work with it will know easier where the flow begins.